# Как определить, что сайт использует динамическую загрузку контента?

Tags: c#, webcrawler

Пишу WebCrawler на с#, который должен парсить контент с кучи сайтов. Важна скорость, по этому в первую очередь сайт парсится обычными гет-запросами.
Но множество сайтов использую динамическую подгрузку контента, а значит мне для них нужен браузер. Использую puppeteer для рендера JS.

Проблема в том, что я далек от веб-технологий и не понимаю, как лучше определять когда действительно необходимо парсить сайт через puppeteer.

Буду благодарен за любые подсказки!

Comment: Если решили написать вменяемый парсер, вам придется пазобраться в веб-технологиях. По поводу инструментов, я бы использовал парсер AngleSharp и его расширение AngleSharp.Js для запуска js скриптов.

Comment: Прямо говоря, это нетривиальный вопрос. Можно легко сказать, когда сайт не использует динамическую подгрузку (нет никаких скриптов, чистый html), а вот как понять по загруженным скриптам, что в них есть динамическая подгрузка -- это очень нетривиальная задача, которая вероятно не имеет общего решения.

Comment: Спасибо, примерно так и думал. 
AngelSharp.js работает шустрее puppeteer?